# Java test case failed due to line separator

Tags: java

I'm doing some test cases on Junit and I just come across this bug with line separator. I know it is caused by the difference in line separator between Mac and Win. I've read some source online and I've tried

```
    @Before
    public void setLineSeparator() {
        System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
    }
```

but it's still not working. I don't want to modify in the configuration and git because there are other people testing on Eclipse and we have to submit it to our teacher. Is there any way to fix this using code? (I'm currently using Junit 4.2). Here is the picture of it

[my_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQZtu.png)

```
    @Test
    public void alert_HailStormWeatherAlert_PrintOutHailStormAlertToTheConsole(){
        ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        EnviroAPPUI.AlerterI alerterI = new EnviroAPPUI.AlerterI();
        Alert alert = new Alert("Weather", 2, new String[] {"Ferris wheel", "restaurants","bowling"});
        alerterI.alert(alert, null);
        assertEquals("*******************************************************************\n"+
                        "Context-aware UV Smart Application Main Menu\n"+
                        "Warning, extreme weather is detected, the current weather event is  hail storm\n"+
                        "Suggestion - please go to: \n"+
                        "Ferris wheel , restaurants , bowling , \n"+
                        "Please select an option\n"+
                        "1. Search for information on a specific item of interest\n"+
                        "2. Search for items of interest in current location\n"+
                        "E. Exit\n",
                outContent.toString());
    }
```

I've tried using to `System.lineSeparator()` but it's still failed.

[after_change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk6Na.png)

failure message

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at main.EnviroAPPUITest.alert_HeavyRainWeatherAlert_PrintOutHeavyRainAlertToTheConsole(EnviroAPPUITest.java:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

I'm using the latest IntelliJ version and java 1.8

Comment: "(I don't want to include my code since it's in the picture already)" See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Would you please include the entire stack trace, pasted into the question as text?

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of setting line separator in the code. This method returns system independent line separator.

Comment: Can you change the expected string to use System.lineSeparator() instead of \n?

Comment: I did. It said *Contents are identical* but still failed

Comment: can you add the failure message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `System.lineSeparator()` to join the lines inside expected value.

I assume that `EnviroAPPUI.printMessage` reads some file using `InputStream` and prints into System.out as is (with system line separator).

This test succeeds for all types of line separators (JUnit 4):

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class LineFailTest {

    @Test public void testWin()  { doTest("\r\n", "test_win.txt");  }
    @Test public void testUnix() { doTest("\n",   "test_unix.txt"); }
    @Test public void testMac()  { doTest("\r",   "test_mac.txt");  }

    private void doTest(String lineSeparator, String fileName) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        print(fileName);
        String actual = outContent.toString();
        assertEquals(String.join(lineSeparator,
            "*******************************************************************",
            "Context-aware UV Smart Application Main Menu",
            "Please select an option",
            "1. Search for information on a specific item of interest",
            "2. Search for items of interest in current location",
            "E. Exit",
            ""
            ),
            actual
        );
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void print(String fileName) {
        try (BufferedInputStream r = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            byte[] bytes = r.readAllBytes();
            System.out.print(new String(bytes));
        }
    }
}
```